# How to create a property in objective c that's also a custom made class?

Tags: objective-c, properties, instantiation, lazy-evaluation

Does anyone know how to add a property in objective c - but that property is also a custom made class?

For instance, I made this class:

```
@interface Person : NSObject

@property NSString *personName;
@property NSNumber *personAge;

-(id)init;

@end
```

Where...

```
@implementation Person

@synthesize personAge, personName;

-(id)init{
    self = [super init];

    if(self){
        self.personAge = [NSNumber numberWithInt:26];
        self.personName = @"Jamie";
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

So basically whenever I init & alloc the Person class, it gets setup with personAge as 26 and personName as Jamie.

Now I want to create a bank account class which contains a person property:

```
@interface BankAccount : NSObject

@property NSNumber *bankAccNumber;
@property (nonatomic) Person *thePerson;

-(id)init;

@end
```

Where...

```
@implementation BankAccount

@synthesize thePerson = _thePerson;
@synthesize bankAccNumber;

    -(id)init{

        self = [super init];

        if(self){
            bankAccNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:999];
        }

        return self;
    }
    @end
```

Now - my issue is this:

1) In the BankAccount class, where do I alloc & init the Person class?

Comment: You're trying to access the `Person` class in the `BackAccount` class?

Comment: There's no **one** right answer except in the context of what you app needs.  You could certainly do it the same place you do `bankAccNumber` if you just want the default `Person`.  (Remember to import Person.h.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stay with your example

```
@implementation BankAccount

@synthesize thePerson = _thePerson;
@synthesize bankAccNumber;

-(id)init{

    self = [super init];

    if(self){
        bankAccNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:999];
        thePerson = [[Person alloc] init];  // <- **** HERE
    }

    return self;
}
@end
```

Of course, in general, you do not want everybody to be 26yo Jamies and have 999$, but I guess you plan to improve on these details later :)